# Resizable textarea inside resizable panel in Ext4

Tags: extjs

I create textarea inside panel and when I mouseover on panel resize handles, then textarea resize handles becomes visible too. How to fix this?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25LTp.png)

```
var resizetxt1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
    fieldLabel: 'Test1',
    height: 80,
    maxHeight: 250,
    resizable: {
        handles: 'all',
    }
});
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'pnl',
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [resizetxt1],
    overflowX: 'auto',
    resizable: {
        handles: 'all'          
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like sencha fix this in extjs 5.

Example in 4.2 : 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rbc

Example in 5.0 :
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rbd